# How to map each parameter in firebase analytics sql to a separate column?

Tags: sql, firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

We use firebase analytics and bigQuery to run sql queries on collected data. This is turning out to be complex as some fields like event_params are repeated records. I want to map each of these repeated fields to separate column.

[image: Repeated Record example]

I want to write queries in the above dataset like finding the difference between minIso and maxIso. How can I define a UDF or a view which can return me the table in the column schema?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I have upvoted your answer because it is helping me out. But as Kartick pointed, it  has not worked for us yet, therefore I'm not marking it as accepted yet.

Comment: it is not clear to me why exactly it does not work for you yet. if you can elaborate it might help me to improve the answer.

Answer (score 6):

> I want to map each of these repeated fields to separate column.

Going direction of pivoting parameters into columns conceptually doable but (in my strong opinion) is a “dead end” in most practical cases
There are many posts here on SO showing how to pivot/transpose rows to columns and the patterns are 1) you just hardcode all possible keys in your query )and obviously no-one likes this) or 2) you create utility query that extracts all keys for you and contracts needed query for you which then you need to execute – so either you do it manually in two steps or you using client of your choice to script those to steps to run in automated way
As I mentioned – there are plenty example of such here on SO

> I want to write queries in the above dataset like finding the difference between minIso and maxIso

If all you need is to do some math with few parameters in the record – see below example

**Dummy Example**: for each `app_instance_idtween` find diff between `coins_awarded` and `xp_awarded`

```
#standardSQL
SELECT user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id,  ARRAY(
  SELECT AS STRUCT name,
    (SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(dim.params) param WHERE key = 'coins_awarded') -
    (SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(dim.params) param WHERE key = 'xp_awarded') diff_awarded
  FROM UNNEST(event_dim) dim
  WHERE dim.name = 'round_completed'  
  ) AS event_dim
FROM `firebase-analytics-sample-data.ios_dataset.app_events_20160607`
WHERE 'round_completed' IN (SELECT name FROM UNNEST(event_dim))
```

with result as

```
Row     app_instance_id                     event_dim.name      event_dim.diff_awarded   
1       02B6879DF2639C9E2244AD0783924CFC    round_completed     226  
2       02B6879DF2639C9E2244AD0783924CFC    round_completed     171  
3       0DE9DCDF2C407377AE3E779FB05864E7    round_completed     25   
...
```

**Dummy Example**: leave whole user_dim intact but replace event_dim with just calculated values

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * REPLACE(ARRAY(
  SELECT AS STRUCT name,
    (SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(dim.params) param WHERE key = 'coins_awarded') -
    (SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(dim.params) param WHERE key = 'xp_awarded') diff_awarded
  FROM UNNEST(event_dim) dim
  WHERE dim.name = 'round_completed'  
  ) AS event_dim)
FROM `firebase-analytics-sample-data.ios_dataset.app_events_20160607`
WHERE 'round_completed' IN (SELECT name FROM UNNEST(event_dim))
```

> This is turning out to be complex as some fields like event_params are repeated records. I want to map each of these repeated fields to separate column.

Hope, from above examples, you can see how really simple it is to deal with repeated fields. I do really recommend you to learn / practice [work with arrays](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays) to gain long term benefits rather than looking for what [wrongly] looks like shortcut

Comment: We take your suggestion to avoid transposing. a) How are we ensuring that we're subtracting the coins_awarded and xp_awarded for the same event? b) Can you update this for the new export schema: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en It will be much easier for me (and others) to understand since it eliminates one level of unnesting c) The inner query returns a name and a diff. Why are we converting that to a struct (SELECT AS STRUCT) and then to an array? Thanks very much.

Comment: @VaddadiKartick - a) this is how BigQuery works when you join table on UNNEST of the repeated record - it joins respective "mini-table" to respective row!

Comment: @VaddadiKartick - c) I provided dummy example where I replaced original `event_dim` with modified one such that it is still repeated record (ARRAY of STRUCTs) but with just two fields - name and diff. Your case/goal can be different - which leads to answer for your b) question - please post new question with your specifics and details and I (or someone else here on SO) will gladly answer it :o)

Comment: Thanks again. I know how UNNEST works, but if you unnest, properties from different events get mixed together in one table, so I'm unable to understand how you're ensuring that we're not subtracting the xp and coins of two different events which, as you know yields the wrong result. My use case isn't different, so there isn't a new question to post. You gave me an example to illustrate your point. Your example seems to use the old BigQuery export schema. I was wondering if it's possible to update it for the new one, which would also be useful to more readers going forward.

Comment: In your example, you wrote something like SELECT ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT name). What happens if you do: SELECT (SELECT name)?

Comment: `SELECT (SELECT name)` is equivalent to `SELECT name`

Comment: if you provide me with reference to dataset with data in new format  - i will take a look for updated example :o)

Comment: the link you provided - does not have reference to table with data in new format, so I cannot play with data to get updated query for you. I will try based on just schema info - but cannot do this on go, so will have time for this only early next week

Comment: Sure, early next week is fine. The link has the new format at the top, and the old format at the bottom (you have to expand it).